# update yes/no attribute programmatically magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have product attribute "is_stock_update_custom". 
I need to update this attribute programmatically from CartController.php

I have tried so Far

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($params['product']);
$attributeCode = "is_stock_update_custom";
$value = "Yes";
$product->setData($attributeCode, $value);
$product->save();
```

In this neither "yes" nor "1" was worked. Please help.

Comment: Can you post your CartController.php with yout code you have tried?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I have added more on question.

Answer (score 0):

> Method 1:

```
$update_resource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$update_resource->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array( $attribute_code => $value), 0);
```

> Method 2:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$resource = $product->getResource();

$product->setData($attribue_code, $value);
$resource->saveAttribute($product, $attribute_code);
```

Comment: I was check this code on another question. this not work.
On method 2 . What about $resource save? Did you try this?

Comment: Have you done reindexing after running the code?